# Can I have a VM on two networks, one host only and one NAT?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 9. My host OS is Windows 7 Enterprise and my guest OS is Windows Server 2008 R2. I understand the three basic types of networking available to a guest OS: bridged, NAT, and host only.

I don't want or need the guest on the same network as the host so I am not using bridged. I want to NAT the internet traffic and I want to also network between the host and guest. I am running this on a notebook computer that I use for development and sometimes I am at home, sometimes at a coffee shop, and sometimes at work. I don't want to screw with the differences between the networks I connect the host with.

So with NAT, that works great so I can get access to the Internet. However, I also need to connect back to the host OS and I would like to be able to network from the host to the guest as well. With host only, this is easy.

What I need is both!

I tried adding a 2nd network adapter and configured it for host only (the first network adapter is configured for NAT), however I think there are other steps I need to take.

Is this possible and what additional configuration steps do I need to take?

Answer (score 0):

You could also configure your NAT adapter to do Port Forwarding for you. VMware has a KB article describing how to do so for a web server.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006955